# Differentiating a similar function to work on a given function

Tags: functional-analysis

If $f(x)$ is a function which is very hard to differentiate, is it okay to work out the x-coordinates of stationary points of $f(x)^2$ and then state that x-coordinate of stationary points of $f(x)^2$ are equal to x-coordinates of stationary points of $f(x)$?

I am asking this because I have used this strategy many times and obtained a correct answer. (E.g calculating the smallest distance between two lines. The distance equation contains a square root. I simply ignore it and math still works out).

If no, are there situations where these methods can work?

If yes to any of the above then, are there any other techniques except squaring the function in which the above strategy can be employed?

Comment: I haven't thought about it too hard, but: one "no-loss-of-information" constraint that you probably want for the $f^2$ trick is that $f$ is everywhere non-negative. For instance if $f(x)=x$ then $f^2$ has a stationary point at 0 which does not exist in the original.

Comment: Oh yes. Got it basically f(x) has to be either all positive or all negative.

Comment: One more thing. If say I have a working domain for f(x) namely a<x<b. At a f(x)=-y. If I used this trick over (f(x)+y)^2, will it work? (Cause now I have everything above 0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, if $g$ is any strict monotonic function, the derivatives of $f$ and $g\circ f$ have the same zeroes.

Standard example: if you want to calculate the stationary points of $\sqrt{\square}$, let $g(x)=x^2$ and happily calculate the stationary points of $\square$.

Other examples are $\ln(\square)$ and $e^{\square}$ with obvious candidates for $g$.

Note: the extra stationary point in Eric's comment is due to the fact that squaring isn't monotonic over the reels.